# How to Overcome 304 Not Modified Issue using Plain JavaScript while importing data from JSON

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a website with HTML,JavaScript and JSON. When, i try to add the data to favorites using "POST" then some cards will get added and other doesn't. When checked the issue it is showing 304 Not Modified as status.Usually
my code is after "POST" pushing the data to JSON i will call "GET" function.But, Sometimes before executing "POST" "GET' will get executed and hence 304 status. Sorry that i couldn't explain better.Please help me.

[image: This is the error i am getting]

As shown in the above picture, when i try to add J.K. Rowling Card it doesn't show up under favorites as in server(mentioned in the image) "GET method" executes first and then "POST Method" executes. Below is my Code

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>

    body{

          background-color : #ddd;
           margin : 0;
    }

    header{
        padding: 1em;
        margin-top:10px;
        background-color: #980;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .container{
        background-color:#82D2DD;
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    .row{
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    .box{
        border-style : solid;
    }
    .card-columns{
        margin:10px;
    }
    .input{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:20px;
    }
    .extra {
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }

</style> 
</head>

<body onload="loadData()">

<header>

   <h1>MovieBuzz</h1>

</header>

<div class="container">

 <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">

    <div id="size" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-2 my-2">
        <div class="card cardwid">
          <div class="h-100"> 
           <div class="card-body flex-fill text-left extra">
                <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
                <p class="card-text"></p>
                <button type="button" id="data-id" class="button btn btn-primary input"></button>
            </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>  
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Favorites</h2>
 <div class="row favrow d-flex align-items-stretch">
   <div id="fav" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-2 my-2">
    <div class="card cardwid">
          <div class="h-100"> 
           <div class="card-body flex-fill text-left extra">
                <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
                <p class="card-text"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let dataList=[], favoriteList=[];

let row=document.querySelector('.row');
let size=document.getElementById('size');
let favrow=document.querySelector('.favrow');
let fav=document.getElementById('fav');
let obj,newsize;

function loadData(){ 
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       if(this.responseText){
          let dataItem;
        try{
              dataItem = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
 }


catch(err){
          console.log("Error!Please Try again later");
        }
           displayData(dataItem); 
           loadFavorites(); 
       }
      }  
    };

xhr.open('GET', ' http://localhost:3000/data', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send();
}

function loadFavorites(){
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
          let favoriteItems;
        try{

          favoriteItems = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log("Error!Please Try again later");
        }

         console.log("GoTO Display Favorites");
         displayFavorites(favoriteItems);   
      }  
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/favorites', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send();

} 

function displayData(dataItem){

dataList=dataItem;

dataItem.forEach(function(data){

  newsize=size.cloneNode(true);

  let newdataname=newsize.querySelector('.card-title');
  newdataname.innerText=data.Name;

  let newdatatext=newsize.querySelector('.card-text');
  newdatatext.innerText=data.Year;

  let  newbutton=newsize.querySelector('.button');
  newbutton.setAttribute('data-id',data.id);
  newbutton.innerText="Add";
  row.appendChild(newsize);

  MoveToFavorites(newbutton, data);

});

row.removeChild(size);

}


function displayFavorites(favoriteItems){

favoriteList=favoriteItems;


obj=fav.cloneNode(true);
favrow.innerHTML="";
fav=obj
favrow.appendChild(fav);

favoriteItems.forEach(function(favorite){


 //console.log(dataList[favorite.favid].Name);
  let newfav=fav.cloneNode(true);

  let newdataname=newfav.querySelector('.card-title');
  newdataname.innerText=dataList[favorite.favid].Name;

  let newdatatext=newfav.querySelector('.card-text');
  newdatatext.innerText=dataList[favorite.favid].Year;

  let  newbutton=row.querySelectorAll('.button')[favorite.favid];//.getAttribute('data-id');
  newbutton.innerText="Remove";

  favrow.appendChild(newfav); 

});

favrow.removeChild(fav);

}

function MoveToFavorites(newbutton,data){

 newbutton.onclick=function(){

        if(newbutton.innerText === "Add"){

          newbutton.innerText="Remove";
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          let url = "http://localhost:3000/favorites";
          xhr.open("POST", url, true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          ///alert("before onreadystatechange");
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
             //alert(this.status);
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 201) {
             favoriteList.push(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));    
         }       
    }; 

    let favdata=JSON.stringify({"favid" :data.id});  
    xhr.send(favdata); 

   }     

    else {

          newbutton.innerText="Add";
          let fav_id;
          console.log("it is not add to favorites");
          favoriteList.forEach(function(favmov){
            if(data.id === favmov.favid)
              fav_id = favmov.id;
          });

          console.log("Favorite Id "+ fav_id);

          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          let url = "http://localhost:3000/favorites/"+fav_id;
          xhr.open("DELETE", url, true);
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

            favoriteList.push(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));

            }
          };
           xhr.send(); 


         }

          loadFavorites(); 
        }


      }
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "Name": "Madam Curie",
      "Year": "7 November 1867"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Name": "Agatha Christie",
      "Year": "15 September 1890"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "Name": "Sidney Sheldon",
      "Year": "11 February 1917"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "Name": "J. K. Rowling",
      "Year": "31 July 1965"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "Name": "Stephen King",
      "Year": "21 September 1947"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "Name": "Stephen Hawking",
      "Year": "8 January 1942"
    }
  ],
  "favorites": [
    {
      "favid": 5,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "favid": 4,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "favid": 3,
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to overcome the 304 Not-Modified Error.While checking the status of the url need to call loadFavorites() function.

```
function MoveToFavorites(newbutton,data){

console.log("In Move TO Favorites");
 newbutton.onclick=function(){

        if(newbutton.innerText === "Add"){

          newbutton.innerText="Remove";
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          let url = 'http://localhost:3000/favorites'; //+ '?_=' + (+(new Date()));
          xhr.open("POST", url, true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

          console.log("Before onreadystatechange");

          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log("After onreadystatechange");
            console.log(i+" times in Func");
            console.log(this.status);
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 201) {
             favoriteList.push(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)); 
             loadFavorites();    
         }
         i=i+1;       
    }; 

    let favdata=JSON.stringify({"favid" :data.id});  
    xhr.send(favdata); 

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 304 status header, is coming from your webserver, either from your "json-server" or some network component before that.

Usually no server will cache POST requests, so this is weird behavior.

Back in the nineties, we added to any request, some timestamp, to avoid cache.

E.g:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/favorites' + '?_=' + (+(new Date()));
// http://localhost:3000/favorites?_=1528899213
```